# rails app - sudden 403 after pull - how do I start to debug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, git

I'm been working on a rails 3.1 app with one other dev.

I've just pulled some of his recent changes, using git. And am now getting a 403 on any page I try to visit.

```
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I'm running the site locally through passenger.

Oddly, when I start the app using rails' internal server. I can visit the site at  http://0.0.0.0:3000

Looking at the changes in this recent pull, the only files have changed are some javascripts, some html the application.rb, routes.rb and a rake file.

How do I debug this, I'm a bit lost on where to start?

---

EDIT:

If I roll back to an earlier version the site works, through passenger. Which leads me to believe the problem is within the rails app, rather than an Apache error. Or it could be a permissions thing, can git change file permissions in this way?

Comment: stacktrace is the first thing to read

Comment: but I'm not getting a rails error, how do I see the stacktrace?

Comment: Check the server log, `/var/log/apache2/whatever.error.log` or something.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is a configuration error in Apache or wrong directory layouts. Make sure that the `passenger_base_uri` still points to the `public` folder inside your rails project and that there are no hidden .htaccess files which block access. Also verify that your sym-links are correct (if there are any). Also check your Apache error log.

Comment: It's still pointing to the public folder and I have no sym-links. I've added some extra info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Start by launching your console to see if rails and your app can be loaded.

In your application root directory type :

`rails console`